# Please help in the solution How equal to the lim

Tags: limits

Please help in the solution

How equal to the lim :

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{cos (2x-h)-cos 2x}{h}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $u=-h$. Does the new limit remind you of something?

Comment: How much output 
MathematicsStudent112

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some substitutions: $y=2x$, $u=-h$

The expression is now $\displaystyle\lim_{u \to 0}-\frac{\cos(y+u)-cos(y)}{u}$, which is $-\frac{d}{dy}\cos y$.

Since $-\frac{d}{dy}\cos y=\sin y$, the final answer is $\sin 2x$.